# ruby multiple blocks in if condition

Tags: ruby, devise

I found this piece of code in devise

```
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class DatabaseAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
      def authenticate!
        resource  = password.present? && mapping.to.find_for_database_authentication(authentication_hash)
        hashed = false

        if validate(resource){ hashed = true; resource.valid_password?(password) }
          remember_me(resource)
          resource.after_database_authentication
          success!(resource)
        end

        mapping.to.new.password = password if !hashed && Devise.paranoid
        fail(:not_found_in_database) unless resource
      end
    end
  end
end
```

updated.
Can someone explain to me why if condition has two blocks

> if validate(resource){ hashed = true;
>   resource.valid_password?(password) }

Comment: All this new code didn't need to be added. The original snippet was sufficient already. Extra context doesn't add any new information.

Comment: There is only one block, not two, and it belongs to the *validate* method. What you mean is that the block contains two statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def validate(p)
  puts "YAY" if block_given?
  false
end

if validate(42){} # ⇐ block being passed to validate
  puts "NEVER PRINTED" # since `validate` returned `false`
end

#⇒ "YAY"
```

Comment: Even  though I know _exactly_ how this thing works, I find it hard to see how this snippet illustrates what is happening. Maybe the example could be improved? Or is it just me?

Comment: Good meditation example, on the other hand, if one is into this stuff. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev In my understanding, this example is crystal clean showing that the block is passing to `validate` rather than to `if`. Happy meditation anyway :)

Comment: No, it's far from being crystal clear. Why `"NEVER PRINTED"` is never printed? (_implicit `nil` return value. Three of them here. One from block, one from `if`, one from `puts`. Which is it?_). I feel that this can be improved without losing the point. :shrug:

Answer (score 2):

It isn't `if` condition that has two blocks. The block enclosed with `{}` is for `validate` method.

BTW this `hashed = true` local variable assignment seems to be useless in this context.

Comment: the local variable assignment makes sense in the expanded version of code. It's irrelevant anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, [`if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-if+Expression) is **not** a [method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html) and you (therefore) can't pass a [block argument](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument) to it, so:

```
if foo(bar) { baz }
  # do something
end
```

is equivalent to:

```
condition = foo(bar) { baz }

if condition
  # do something
end
```

You could also replace the above `{ ... }` with a `do ... end` block:

```
if foo(bar) do
    baz
  end
  # do something
end
```

This is just for demonstration purposes, please don't write such code.

The above would still be equivalent to:

```
condition = foo(bar) do
  baz
end

if condition
  # do something
end
```

Comment: `if foo(bar, &->() { baz })` notation is always cleaner, but it creates a redundant intermediate `Proc` object, while passing block as is does not.

Comment: In a `while` loop, you can use `do` instead of a newline to terminate the condition, just like you can use `then` in a conditional `if`  or `case` expression. If you want your code to be *really* confusing, you could play around with `do`/`end` blocks inside a `do` terminated conditional of a `while` loop.

Comment: @mudasobwa you could put parentheses around the whole condition: `if (foo(bar) { baz })` but I would probably just put the result into a variable.